# Animating indirect lighting

Tags: light, baking

I'm animating a scene with lightning, and I want the lightning to light up the scene for a few frames, then die out. I've already animated the lighting, but when I try to bake indirect lighting, it only bakes one frame. How do I have the light change with the animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no simple/automatic option in Blender to have light probes change/bake over time, so you have to do it via scripting.

- Select the Scripting workspace
- Create a New script
- Copy, paste, and modify the below code: change the Path value to wherever you want to output your animation frames, and change the range of frames you want to output. The sample below will save frame 0-29 (does not include 30).

```
import bpy

scn = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]
com = bpy.ops.scene 
path = "d:/blender/output/frame_"
i = 0
for i in range (0,30):
    scn.frame_current = i
    com.light_cache_bake()
    scn.render.filepath = path + str(scn.frame_current)
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

- Run the script (click Run Script or the play button, depends on version)

Basically what this is doing is going through each frame, performing the "bake indirect lighting" option (the one you manually click under the Render settings), rendering the frame & saving it as frame_0.png, frame_1.png, etc. So it will take a while and there's no "cancel" option, so I'd suggest testing this with a short range of frames to begin with. It may appear as if Blender has crashed, but if you keep an eye on the Path folder, you should see files start to be saved as they render.

When using this method, I only use it for the frames where the lighting changes. I wouldn't want to output the *entire* animation like this (ie, baking each frame when nothing changes). So I might render frame 0-100 normally, then if my light probe needs to change on frame 101, output frame 101 to 110 with this method, then render the remainder normally & composite everything in After Effects later.

Full credit to the person who came up with this method, as demonstrated here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAAb6sITkq4

Hope this helps!

Comment: It worked! If you could answer one more question though, how would you substitute those frames into the animation? Thanks!

Comment: You need to composite all the frames together in something like After Effects or even Blender can do it. You basically drag in the frames you rendered normally, then the frames you rendered using the method from my answer, then render them out them as a movie file. There are tutorials on how to convert an image sequence into a movie here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pNUxRSWTC4 and here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO8mNHLTEac

Comment: Does this also include the Compositor being run, or does that need something else to run it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Reflection CubeMap to use it in real time without baking
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do it by adding the objects that don’t move plus the lighting to a collection and then call it ‘static’ then use the collection in the light probe. The animated objects would use the bounce lighting data